# html in python to send e mails

Tags: python, html

I am new to python and I am trying to send e-mails from python. I would like to add some python code inside my html, but it doesn't seem to work. In fact I used the {%} inside the html code but i have an error telling me that is an invalid syntax. Below an extract of my code :

```
import win32com.client as client
from datetime import date

outlook = client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
message.Display()
message.To = 'XXXXXX'

message.Subject = 'Data update '+ str(date.today())
message.HTMLBody = f"""<div> Hi, <br> Here is the report of the data update : </div>

<br> <br> <b> <u> Bases : </u> </b>
<br> The update of the following databases failed : 
<br> {%for value in range len(final_result):
            final_result['Tables'][value] +" : "+ final_result['date_donnees'][value]%}
<br> <br> Les reportings ayant échoué sont : {failed_reports} """


message.Save() # save to drafts folder
message.Send() # send to outbox
```

The dataframe "final_result" are of course declared a little higher in the code.

Does anyone know how to deal with this ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your string outside of the HTML, and just include it as a string.

```
res = ""
for value in range(len(final_result)):
    res += final_result['Tables'][value] + " : " + final_result['date_donnees'][value]

message.HTMLBody = f"""...
<br> {res}
..."""
```

I'm not sure `len(final_result)` is the right answer, but see if this gets you closer.

Answer (score 0):

It is working really well ! Thank you very much.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to come back to line at each iteration inside the res variable ? I tried to use the "\n" at the beginning like this :
`res += "\n" + final_result['Tables'][value] + " : " + final_result['date_donnees'][value]`

When i make a simple print it is working really well, but inside the e-mail it doesn't respect this formatting, i get all the lines stucked between them.